# Sharepoint.Utility replacements

Tags: c#, sharepoint, nuget, sharepoint-2013, csom

I have been using different Sharepoint.Client nuget packages because of different framework targets and I am unable to find any resource describing the differences between them.

But more importantly some are missing SPUtility class. Seems like a shoddy design but has some useful methods like the one I am using

```
SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime)
```

My question is does anyone know where I should be looking for the same functionality or is it dead and buried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same can be achieved with

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

But leaving this open for a day because I would like a more complete answer, fx. if the same ISO format resides in the library elsewhere or if anyone has a better way of passing universal DateTime data to SP.

Comment: Using `DateTime.Today` I receive "today - 1", why? Only `Datime.Now` fix the problem.